# CSS position: relative vs position: absolute

Tags: css, css-position

I'm trying to figure out how to clear or reset the relative positioning of an element on my page.  I have an element with `position:relative`, and further down the tree a bit a dialog box div is defined along with a background image that is stretched to fill the page to make the dialog box modal.

The problem is that b/c there is a position:relative further up the DOM tree, when I say `top:0`, `left:0` for the background image, it goes to `0,0` relative of that element rather than going to 0,0 of the page.

How can I clear or reset the relative positioning so that the absolutely positioned background image can be set to `0,0` of the page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In most cases, your modal should be a direct child of the body.

If the modal has an ancestor with relative or absolute positioning, you cannot "undo" that short of changing the style on the offending element.

HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>...</head>
    <body>
        <div id="content">content!</div>
        <div id="someModal" class="modal" style="display:none"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.modal {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
}
```

Comment: And if I cant get the modal to be a direct child of body (due to master pages/user controls/etc..) then the only way to achieve what I need is to use javascript to remove the modal from the DOM and then append it to the body?  Or is there another way?

Comment: using JS to move the modal to the body is a perfectly reasonable solution, yes.

Comment: Removing the modal from the DOM and appending it back to body has worked perfectly.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We would love to see your code first, but probably you're looking nto this:

```
position: absolute !important;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, an absolutely positioned element that is set at (0,0) will ALWAYS got to the (0,0) corner of its closest parent element that is position relative. This is the defined behavior and cannot be altered.

Since you are absolutely positioning the modal, I'd suggest pulling out out of the relatively positioned element and just sticking it under either (a) a non-positioned parent, or (b) just after the body tag.

EDIT: Johnathan beat me to it!